# How to find the angle of an object by given four coordinates?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

The object (camera) can be in positions with rotation of $0°, 45°, 90°, 135°, 180°, 225°, 270°, 315°$.

The known values are the coordinates points of $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$. The camera is at $(0,0)$.

How can I find in which of the above angles the camera is?

So an example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnPie.jpg

We know the camera is at $(0,0)$.
And the points:

1. $(-6,16)$
2. $(6,16)$
3. $(6,3)$
4. $(-6,3)$

Is there a mathematical way to find that the camera is at the position with angle $0°$?

Comment: So is the coordinate system always tied to the camera? So that the camera is always at $(0,0)$?

Comment: This subject is covered in books on compter vision. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695043/how-does-one-convert-world-coordinates-to-camera-coordinates

Comment: @MattiP.  Yes the camera is always at (0,0)